# Mockito with method which returns a boolean is not considered by my code

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

In my Java code, I would like to mock with Mockito a method which return a boolean.
In fact it concerns a parking application to calculate price for parking. In my tests with Junit5 and Mockito, I mock a method which return a boolean to calculate price with a reduce if this boolean is true. But my mock is not working and I don't know why...

```
when(ticketDao.isRegularCustomer(any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

I want this mock can work to calculate price with a reduce.
Thanks for helping, here is my code.

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class FareCalculatorServiceTest {

    private static FareCalculatorService fareCalculatorService;
    private Ticket ticket;

    @Mock
    private static TicketDao ticketDao;

    @BeforeAll
    private static void setUp() {
        fareCalculatorService = new FareCalculatorService();

    }

    @BeforeEach
    private void setUpPerTest() {
        ticket = new Ticket();
        //when(ticketDao.isRegularCustomer(any())).thenReturn(false);
    }


    @Test
    public void feature2CalculateFareBikeWith5PerCentReduceIfRegularCustomer(){
        Date inTime = new Date();
        inTime.setTime( System.currentTimeMillis() - (45 * 60 * 1000) );//45MIN IN PARKING
        Date outTime = new Date();
        ParkingSpot parkingSpot = new ParkingSpot(1, ParkingType.BIKE,false);

        when(ticketDao.isRegularCustomer(any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);

        ticket.setInTime(inTime);
        ticket.setOutTime(outTime);
        ticket.setParkingSpot(parkingSpot);

        fareCalculatorService.calculateFare(ticket); 

        assertEquals((0.75 * Fare.BIKE_RATE_PER_HOUR-((0.75 * Fare.BIKE_RATE_PER_HOUR) * 5/100)), ticket.getPrice());
    }
```

here this is the code under test

```
public void calculateFare(Ticket ticket) {

    //resultTime is used to calculate parking's cost.
    float resultTime;

    if ((ticket.getOutTime() == null) || (ticket.getOutTime().before(ticket.getInTime()))) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out time provided is incorrect:" + ticket.getOutTime().toString());
    }

    long inHour = ticket.getInTime().getTime();
    long outHour = ticket.getOutTime().getTime();
    //TODO: Some tests are failing here. Need to check if this logic is correct
    long duration = outHour - inHour;

    if (duration < ((30 * 60 * 1000))) {
      resultTime = 0; //if duration is less than 30min, the cost is free for customer and result time is automatically set at 0.
    } else {
      resultTime = ((((float) duration / 1000) / 60) / 60);
    }

    if (ticketDao.isRegularCustomer(ticket.getVehicleRegNumber())) {
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
      System.out.println(" ----- 5% REDUCE ON OVERALL COST -----");
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

      switch (ticket.getParkingSpot().getParkingType()) {
        case CAR: {
          ticket.setPrice((resultTime * Fare.CAR_RATE_PER_HOUR) - ((resultTime * Fare.CAR_RATE_PER_HOUR) * 5 / 100));
          System.out.println(ticket.getPrice());
          break;
        }
        case BIKE: {
          ticket.setPrice((resultTime * Fare.BIKE_RATE_PER_HOUR) - ((resultTime * Fare.BIKE_RATE_PER_HOUR) * 5 / 100));
          System.out.println(ticket.getPrice());
          break;
        }
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Parking Type");
      }

    } else {
      switch (ticket.getParkingSpot().getParkingType()) {
        case CAR: {
          ticket.setPrice(resultTime * Fare.CAR_RATE_PER_HOUR);
          System.out.println(resultTime * Fare.CAR_RATE_PER_HOUR);
          break;
        }
        case BIKE: {
          ticket.setPrice(resultTime * Fare.BIKE_RATE_PER_HOUR);
          System.out.println(resultTime * Fare.BIKE_RATE_PER_HOUR);
          break;
        }
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Parking Type");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code under test

Comment: BTW: Do not longer use the old `java.util.Date`. Use the modern `java.time` API

Comment: See my answer. You'll have to set your mock into your service.

Comment: I think, you could delete the code TicketDao.java in your post. It's unrelevant in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to set your ticketDao's mock into the fareCalculatorService :

- With a setter (in your method or in a @Before method)
- With an @InjectMocks annotation in the declaration of fareCalculatorService in your test class

Like that :

```
@InjectMocks
private static FareCalculatorService fareCalculatorService;
```

If you do this, you'll have to delete your @BeforeAll's method.